# What is the best way to create multipart upload to a presigned url in aws s3 bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I want to generate a presign url(with upload rights only) and share it with my second application, so the second application can upload multipart file to it. How can I achieve this with java + spring boot ?
P.S. all the solutions I googled work only for single upload but not for multipart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GeneratePresignedUrlRequest`, try this ;

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(S3_BUCKET_NAME, key);
generatePresignedUrlRequest.addRequestParameter("uploadId", uploadIdentifier);
generatePresignedUrlRequest.addRequestParameter("partNumber", Integer.toString(partNumber))
generatePresignedUrlRequest.putCustomRequestHeader(Headers.CONTENT_MD5, md5Hash);
generatePresignedUrlRequest.putCustomRequestHeader(Headers.CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(contentLength));
```